# Find all solutions for $z^3 = \overline{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $z = a + ib$ and that $\overline{z} = a - ib$, but when I try and calculate the solutions I get an unsolvable equation.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about real and imaginary parts and note that every solution $z$ is such that $|z|^3=|z^3|=|\bar z|=|z|$ hence $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$. Furthermore, $z^4=z^3\cdot z=\bar z\cdot z=|z|^2$.

Can you finish in both cases?

Comment: Shouldn't I use the real and imaginary numbers as the solutions? For example:  |z|=1 then:
 |z|= |a + ib|  --->
 |z|^2 = a^2 + b^2 --->
 |z| = sqare of (a^2+b^2) = 1 
 a^2+b^2 = 1.   Not sure what to do from this point.

Comment: The method using modulus and argument is swift and painless. But if you prefer the path of suffering, please use real and imaginary parts (only, I prefer not to walk this path with you).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the modulus. Can you show me how to finish the two cases with this method?

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant if you can you show me how to solve with the modulus method you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

First note that, if $|z|=r$, then $|z^3|=|z|^3=|\overline{z}|=|z|$, giving $r\in\{0,1\}$, so $z=0$ works and $z=1 \text{cis } \theta$ works, for some $\theta$. Plugging in gives $z^3=\text{cis } 3\theta$ and $\overline{z}=\text{cis } -\theta$, so we have $ 3 \theta \equiv -\theta \pmod {2\pi} $.

That means that $4\theta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$, which is true iff $\theta$ is a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Can you finish?