# Solution of $z^3 + 3z^2 + 3z = \overline z$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find all complex numbers which satisfy the equation and I don't know how.

> $$z^3 + 3z^2 + 3z = \overline z$$

Thanks for help

Comment: Use $w=z+1$ and [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067784/find-all-solutions-for-z3-overlinez?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write it as $z^3 + 3z^2 + 3z + 1= \overline {z + 1}$.

Hint #2: let $w=z+1$ then the equation becomes $w^3 = \overline w$.

Hint #3: $\;\;w^3 = \overline w \;\implies\; | w^3 | = | \overline w | \;\implies\; | w|^3 = | w |\;$ which means $|w|=0$ or $|w|=1$.

- If $|w|=0$ then $w=0$ and $z=w-1=-1$ which is one solution to the original equation.
- If $|w|=1 \iff w \overline w = 1$ then $\overline w = \frac{1}{w}$ and the equation becomes $w^4=1$, which gives $4$ more solutions in $w$ which in turn translate to $4$ more solutions in $z$.

Comment: Should I write: z as a+bi, because when I do so I come to a big equation.

Comment: $z^3+3z^2+3z+1=(z+1)^3$

Comment: @MarušaJ You want to defer that $z=a+bi$ substitution for as long as possible, precisely because the equations become big. See my edit.

Comment: I get bi=1 at the end. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @MarušaJ Don't know since you didn't show the derivation, but maybe you turned to $z=a+bi$ too early. See the latest edit.

Comment: @dxiv Uhh sorry but I'm kinda confused about this question as well , if $|w|=1$ then $|z+1|=1$ so that would be a circle of centre (-1,0) and radius 1?

Comment: @dydxx If you read to the end, $|w|=1$ is a necessary condition, but *not* a sufficient one. The necessary *and* sufficient condition is $w^4=1$.